# How do I unit test a Rails model that returns a different model object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rspec

I have defined a `User` model and a `Profile`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile

  def current_profile
    profile || create_profile
  end
end
```

So the `current_profile` method either returns the existing profile or creates a new one and returns it.  How do I write a unit test for the `User` to check that this method works properly?  Should I somehow check that the returned object is a Profile object? Or should I just check the profile's parameters? I am using RSpec not minitest.

Comment: Two quick questions: (1) Are you testing `User` or `Role`? Your question states `User`, but your code declares `Role`, and (2) are you asking about the specific expectations to set in your tests? If so, I have some thoughts for you.

Comment: I am testing `User` here -- I copy/pasted the wrong code when I threw together the sample here, sorry about that.  I will update the original post.  And yes, I am not sure what the expectations should be here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
describe User do
  describe 'current_profile' do
    context 'when there is an existing profile' do
      before(:each) do
        @profile = User.current_profile # creates a profile
      end
      it 'should return the existing profile' do
        expect(User.current_profile).to eq(@profile)
      end
      it 'should not change Profile.count' do # assuming you have a Profile Class
        expect{User.current_profile}.not_to change{Profile.count}
      end
      it 'should return a Profile object' do
        expect(@profile).to be_a(Profile)
      end
    end
    context 'when there is no existing profile' do
      it 'should change Profile.count by 1' do
        expect{User.current_profile}.to change{Profile.count}.by(1)
      end
      it 'should return a Profile object' do
        @profile = User.current_profile
        expect(@profile).to be_a(Profile)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very similar to what I ended up doing.  For checking that a Profile object is returned, I ended up using something like `expect(@profile).to be_a(Profile)` rather than `is_a?`, which seems more idiomatic.

Comment: Also, would you please (a) post your solution and accept it or (b) accept mine - for completeness? Thanks!

Comment: Another thing I caught -- `expect{User.current_profile}.to change{Profile.count}.by(0)` could just be written as `expect{User.current_profile}.not_to change{Profile.count}`

Answer (score 1):

You should test for both cases:

*either returns the existing profile OR creates a new one and returns it*

using contexts:

```
describe 'User' do
  describe 'current_profile' do
    context 'when there is an existing profile' do
      it 'should return the existing profile' do
        # call and test expectations
      end
    end

    context 'when there is no existing profile' do
      it 'should create and return the profile' do
        # call and test expectations
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also remember to cover the case when the Role itself is a new_record. In which case create_profile may fail as it would expect a role id which doesn't exist yet.